# Rust borrow mutable self inside match expression

Tags: rust

I have a problem with `self` borrowing in a `match` expression:

```
fn add_once(&'t mut self, p_name: &'t str) -> Box<Element> {
    match self.get(p_name) {
        Some(x) => Box::new(*x),
        None => self.add(p_name),
    }
}
```

The signature of the `get()` and `add()` functions are:

```
fn get(&self, p_name: &str) -> Option<&Element>
fn add(&'t mut self, p_name: &'t str) -> Box<Element>
```

The compiler refuses this code:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:38:21
   |
36 |         match self.get(p_name) {
   |               ---- immutable borrow occurs here
37 |             Some(x) => Box::new(*x),
38 |             None => self.add(p_name),
   |                     ^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
39 |         }
40 |     }
   |     - immutable borrow ends here
```

I get that, but I don't see how I can rewrite the `match` expression.

In a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23032464/rust-cannot-borrow-self-as-mutable-because-self-history-is-also-borrow), it was solved by having the `match` return a value and then calling the function. However, that doesn't work here because the meaning of the conditional is not to choose a value but selectively execute an action.

The full code sample is below:

```
struct Element<'e> {
    name: &'e str, 
}

impl<'e> Element<'e> {
    fn new(p_name: &str) -> Element {
        Element { name: p_name }
    }
}

struct Top<'t> {
    list: Vec<Element<'t>>,
}

impl<'t> Top<'t> {
    fn new() -> Top<'t> {
        Top { list: vec![] }
    }

    fn get(&self, p_name: &str) -> Option<&Element> {
        for element in self.list.iter() {
            if element.name == p_name {
                return Some(element);
            }
        }
        None
    }

    fn add(&'t mut self, p_name: &'t str) -> Box<Element> {
        let new_element = Box::new(Element::new(p_name));
        self.list.push(*new_element);
        return new_element;
    }

    fn add_once(&'t mut self, p_name: &'t str) -> Box<Element> {
        match self.get(p_name) {
            Some(x) => Box::new(*x),
            None => self.add(p_name),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut t = Top::new();
    let plop1 = t.add_once("plop1");
    let plop2 = t.add_once("plop1");
}
```

Comment: Even without the mutable error, you would still have a type-unification issue. Both branches of `match` should return the same type. Similarly, I am surprised that `add` compiles as you first `push` into the vector and then return; however it seems to me that pushing into the vector should invalidate (move) the content of the box... Shouldn't `add` return `&Element` and the result of `add_once` be `&Element` ?

Comment: @MatthieuM., it works because `Element` is `Copy`, so `*new_element` returns a copy of the element.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev: ah yes, I had forgotten `Copy` was not yet opt-in. Still, it seems to me this indicate a design flaw: `Top` seems like it should be generic, and work on non-`Copy` types.

Comment: I'm very new to Rust, so there are probably design errors. Top should indeed work on non-`Copy` types.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Initially, I wanted `add` and `add_once` to return `&Element`, but couldn't get it working.

Answer (score 3):

Let's fix the design issues first. The main issue is lifetime conflation:

```
struct Top<'t> {
    list: Vec<Element<'t>>,
}

impl<'t> Top<'t> {
    fn add(&'t mut self, p_name: &'t str) -> Box<Element>;
    fn add_once(&'t mut self, p_name: &'t str) -> Box<Element>;
}
```

You assert that `self` should live at least as long as `'t`, which is itself the lifetime bound of the references it will contain. It is not actually what you need, `self` should live *less* than `'t` to guarantee that any `&'t` is still alive and kicking until `self` dies.

If we change this, we can painlessly return references to `Element`:

```
impl<'t> Top<'t> {
    fn add<'a>(&'a mut self, p_name: &'t str) -> &'a Element<'t>;
    fn add_once<'a>(&'a mut self, p_name: &'t str) -> &'a Element<'t>;
}
```

Note that the lifetime `'a` of the reference to `Element` is different (and actually will be shorter) than the lifetime `'t` of its contained reference.

With that out of the way, this should fix the functions:

```
fn position(&self, p_name: &str) -> Option<usize> {
    self.list.iter().position(|e| e.name == p_name)
}

fn add<'a>(&'a mut self, p_name: &'t str) -> &'a Element<'t> {
    self.list.push(Element::new(p_name));
    &self.list[self.list.len() - 1]
}

fn add_once<'a>(&'a mut self, p_name: &'t str) -> &'a Element<'t> {
    if let Some(p) = self.position(p_name) {
        return &self.list[p];
    }
    self.add(p_name)
}
```

And `position` can be reused for `get`:

```
fn get<'a>(&'a self, p_name: &str) -> Option<&'a Element<'t>> {
    self.position(p_name).map(|pos| &self.list[pos])
}
```

---

I would expect the following to work in a perfect world:

```
fn add_once<'a>(&'a mut self, p_name: &'t str) -> &'a Element<'t> {
    match self.get(p_name) {
        Some(x) => x,
        None => self.add(p_name)
    }
}
```

However, I recall a discussion in which it was determined that the borrow-checker was not lax enough: the scope of the borrow induced by `self.get` is computed to be the entire `match` expression even though in the `None` branch the temporary cannot be accessed.

This should be fixed once "Non-Lexical Lifetimes" are incorporated in Rust, which is a work in progress.

Comment: You are entirely correct in your "perfect world" remark. This does not work because borrows are lexical, but they will probably become non-lexical in future, which would allow such pattern. As far as I remember, this was one of the main reasons of introducing `Entry` API in maps in `libstd` (the other one is the desire to reduce amount of lookups, of course).

Comment: @VladimirMatveev: I hope it will be extended, the use of irrefutable patterns in `if` is a good work-around, but it means losing the exhaustiveness check of `match`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thanks, I understand lifetimes a bit more. In fact, `add` and `add_once` return references that have a different lifetime from the element itself. Needs a little brain-gym, but seems nice. However, the compiler complains on `fn<'a>`, shouldn't it be `fn add<'a>` ? Or is it a new syntax ? Furthermore, the `if let` syntax is experimental in v0.12. The syntax with `match` looked really clean.

Comment: @Tifauv': Sorry for the `fn<'a>` the lifetime is after the function name indeed. I agree the `match` syntax is cleaner, however it does not work at the moment as explained in my note.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to have a race condition between the `push` and `index` ?  If `Vec.push` returned the inserted element, it would be more simple.

Comment: @Tifauv': It would be simpler but it is not possible (yet), as for race conditions there is no worry because a `&mut T` pointer guarantees that no-one else is reading/writing to the object at the moment (there is no other alias in use). It's a guarantee that is very peculiar to the Rust ownership system.

Comment: @MatthieuM. OK, I forgot about the `&mut T`. Rust has some unique concepts that take some time to get right. I tried the modifications you proposed, and it still doesn't compile. First, in `add`, `Vec.index` takes a reference to the index, not the index itself so I first create `let idx = self.list.len() - 1;` then call `self.list.index(&idx)`. However, the compiler still refuses the `if let Some(x) = self.get(p_name) {` with the message **cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements**. Maybe it works with nightly build and not 0.12 ?

Comment: @Tifauv': I am not compiling actually, as I don't have 0.12 handy anyway. Since `Option` contains a reference, you might need a `Some(ref x)` to indicate that `x` is a reference.

Comment: @MatthieuM. That didn't work. `x` is indeed a reference, and is what I want to return, so I had to modify the return line as `return *x`. I get the same error as in my previous message.