# Right way to access an enum variant's field that is itself a field of a struct

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a struct `App`:

```rust
struct App {
   cmd: Command
}
```

that owns a command of type `Command`:

```rust
enum Command {
   Cmd1 { flag: bool }
}
```

(I use StructOpt to derive a command line interface from that.)

To execute the right command I have a function like this:

```rust
impl App {
    fn execute(&mut self) {
        match &self.cmd {
            Command::Cmd1 { flag } => self.do_cmd1(*flag)
        };
    }
}
```

where I handle the actual execution in an extra function `do_cmd1(&mut self, flag: bool)` to keep `execute` clean.
However, this does not work since in `self.do_cmd1(*flag)` I borrow `self` as mutable and also as immutable via `*flag` which belongs to `cmd` which in turn belongs to `self`.

My question is: What would be the proper way to access `flag` in `do_cmd1` that respects the borrowing rules?

Clarification: I need this to also work for things like

```rust
enum Command {
    Cmd2 { text: String }
}
```

where the variant's field is not `Copy`.

Comment: With the "clarification", I think this is a duplicate of several other questions, such as [Cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because `self.history[..]` is also borrowed as immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23032464/3650362), [How can I call a mutating method while holding a reference to self?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27335252/3650362), and perhaps [Passing mutable self reference to method of owned object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30681468/3650362) (that last one swaps the receiver and argument of `do_cmd1` but the suggestions of the answers apply just as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move or copy the flag out of `self` before calling `do_cmd1`, the borrows don't need to overlap.

```
    fn execute(&mut self) {
        match self.cmd {
            Command::Cmd1 { flag } => self.do_cmd1(flag),
        };
    }
```

The only changes are removing the `&` from `&self.cmd` and the `*` from `*flag`.

The above works because `bool` is a `Copy` type. For types that are not `Copy`, you will need to do some extra work to ensure the borrows do not overlap, as in these related questions:

- [Cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because `self.history[..]` is also borrowed as immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23032464/cannot-borrow-self-as-mutable-because-self-history-is-also-borrowed-as)
- [How can I call a mutating method while holding a reference to self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27335252/how-can-i-call-a-mutating-method-while-holding-a-reference-to-self)
- [Passing mutable self reference to method of owned object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30681468/passing-mutable-self-reference-to-method-of-owned-object)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right, this solution works for `Copy` types. It does not work for types like `String` which you might also like to have as a command parameter. I will clarify my question.

Comment: @Andreas I have edited the answer to add links to some other questions that I think answer the question. Do these help?

Comment: The two main strategies will probably be cloning the `String` inside the `match` and calling `do_cmd1` outside (so the borrows aren't live at the same time), or redefining `do_cmd1` to not borrow all of `self` (so the borrows don't refer to the same thing).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out those related questions. I agree with your conclusion about the two solutions that work in this case (since using StructOpt prevents altering the types in `App` and `Command`). @phimuemue's answer goes into a similar direction. I think, I like `do_cmd1` not borrowing all of `self` best and am going to implement that. I wil accept your answer. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I have come up with, although I think there should be a better one:

Extend the `Command` enum in the following way:

```rust
impl Command {
    fn get_cmd1_flag(&self) -> Option<bool> {
        match &self {
            Command::Cmd1 { flag } => Some(*flag),
            _ => None
        }
    }
}
```

Then, alter the signature of `do_cmd1` to `do_cmd1(&mut self)` (i.e. remove the `flag` argument).
To access `flag` inside of `do_cmd1` you can just call `self.cmd.get_cmd1_flag()` and handle the `Option`.
Together with proper return types and use of the `?` operator this is even quite comfortable to write.

What I dislike about this solution is that you somehow implement an own layer of type checking, which is why I think there should be a more elegant way. But at least this works.

Answer (score 0):

Does `do_cmd1` really need to be a method of `App`?

In other words: You may be able to separate the `cmd` and the "other", non-`cmd` part (let's call it `Executor`) and put them in different fields of your struct:

```
struct App {
   cmd: Command
   exe: Executor
}

impl App {
    fn execute(&mut self) {
        match &self.cmd {
            Command::Cmd1 { flag } => self.exe.do_cmd1(*flag)
        };
    }
}
```

This way, it is clear which parts of `self` are *actually* borrowed mutably.